# Parse - Android - Text trimmed on default push notification

Tags: android, text, parse-platform, push-notification, string-length

Is there some way to set NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle() on the default Parse's push notification handler?
When I send one push containing "alert" field, the sdk shows the notification with the default style and the text it's trimmed.

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize your "data" payload. Instead of the usual

```
Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [ "Giants", "Mets" ],
  data: {
    alert: "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3."
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

You'll have to craft your payload to something like this for example:

```
var myData = {

  action:"com.yourcompany.blahblah.UPDATE_SOMETHING", // take note of this!!!
  message:"You are awesome",
  somethingelse:3
};

 // Note: some "data" field names are reserved

     Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [ "Mets" ],
  data: myData
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

You can see this in the docs: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#options-data/JavaScript

And then, on your Android client:

1.) Remove these tags in your manifest file

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

2.) Craft your own BroadcastReceiver (I suggest a WakefulBroadcastReceiver type), that then fires off an IntentService, to display the notification. This broadcast receiver listens to the action you specified earlier in your custom data payload:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.yourcompany.blahblah.MyCustomReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.yourcompany.blahblah.UPDATE_SOMETHING" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

3.) In your IntentService (of course registered in your manifest file as well), you can then extract the "pushed" data as json from the Intent's extras, and craft however you want your Notification to appear:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        final Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(extras.getString("com.parse.Data"));
        // keys matching your myData payload object names/keys
        final String message = json.getString("message"); 
        final int somethingelse = json.getInt("somethingelse");

        // YOUR code to compose the Notification however you want it to appear follows here
```

**EDIT:**

Another method:

1.) Create a new class that extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver (https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParsePushBroadcastReceiver.html)

2.) Override the methods particularly getNotification(Context context, Intent intent)

3.) compose your BigStyle notification from there

Comment: I know that and I'm using that feature. But when you send a simple push from Parse's platform, the default payload contains the default field "alert". My question was pointing that, I need to teel to Parse default handler that can use the BigContentView. Or if it is not possible, override the default handler, but I have not found someway to do that.

Comment: I see, I updated my answer to try out another way of doing it (still using the default payload)

Comment: The last method did not work either. Parse never calls the extended BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: In the manifest, did you change the receiver to point to your class? Note that with the second method, the 2 receiver elements must exist in your manifest

Comment: Yes, I've changed the manifest... without that there's no test.